# How to insert extra elements into an Affinity Publisher Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, affinity-publisher

So I've done most of the layouting for a project and I've just generated a table of contents. It's all working well except I just realised that the chapter headings I had created using the artistic text rule with my Heading 1 style don't get picked up by the table of contents. I believe this is because I have put them in an Artistic Text Tool frame rather than a normal Text Frame.

However I would still like the chapter titles to show up in the table of contents obviously. Is my only option to recreate the chapter headings inside of a normal Text Frame? Or to somehow make an invisible heading in a text frame that will get picked up by the table of contents generator but not actually displayed?

Neither of those options seem ideal, so is there some other way to insert elements into a table of contents? I've tried just adding the chapter headings to the table of contents manually but that breaks as soon as the table of contents needs updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it seems the premise of the question may have been incorrect. Artistic text will show up in the table of contents. The problem was that I had applied a "Character Style" to the artistic text, rather than a "Paragraph Style". If I change the character style to a paragraph style (you may need to also set the character style of the artistic text to "no style" and then reselect the paragraph style for it to properly apply) then the headings appear in the table of contents as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Hide the real header with a white box and place the artistic header on top of the box.

Here's my TOC:

[image]

Here's my page 2:

[image]

As well you could write the real header with paper or 100% transparent color. I do not recommend it because it's invisible when you may want to see it.

Page 2 after moving the box and the artistic header aside:

[image]

You can keep the artistic header and the rectangle as a group which is pinned as a floating object to the text, so they will follow the layout changes. Simply disable the group in the layers panel if you want to access the header.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was going to accept it, but then found I could make Artistic text show up in the table of contents. Could you look at my answer and see if there is a problem with it? If not I will accept my answer. If there is some issue I'm not seeing then I might accept yours instead.

Comment: @Rhys   Artistic text doesn't have many unique decoration possibilities before it's converted to curves. It can get effects but so do normal text. Also normal text can be converted to curves. The main difference is free scalability. I guessed your artistical headers are actually drawings. My fault - sorry!